# How do I get a list for each column with the smallest width value using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have some objects title that also have the properties column and width.

Examples for title objects:

```
column (int)      width (double)
0                  100
0                  150
3                  85
3                  110
```

I need a list with the object Tuple<int, double> with two entries for my example:

```
Tuple<0, 100>
Tuple<3, 85>
```

The list has the smallest width value for each column.
How can I implement this with LINQ?

Thanks.

I have started with:
`var result = title.GroupBy(c => c.Column).Select(x => new Tuple<int, double>(c.Column, c.Width))`

But I don't know what to do.
I need only one Tuple entry with the value of the smallest width for each column.

Comment: `GroupBy(..).Select(x=>Tuple.Create(x.Key, x.Min(x=>x.Width)))` ?

Answer (score 2):

Linq query seems to be direct:

```
var result = title
  .GroupBy(item => item.column, item => item.width)
  .Select(group => (column : group.Key, width : group.Min()))
  .ToList();
```

Here we

- `Group` initial collection (`title`) by `column`, each group consists of `width`
- For each `group` we create a named `Tuple` - `column` and `Min` width
- Finally, we materialize `result` into a list.

Comment: Typo: Last call should be `.ToList()`, not `.List()`.

Comment: @Orion: You are quite right, thank you! I've edited the answer.